# Start the table from a specific column excel apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf, hssf

I'm having a problem in excel while using Apache POI. I can create  rows, but sometimes I'm in a situation where I would like to start from a particular column only.

So is it possible to start any particular column like the 'C' column Instead of the column 'A' Always.

I'm using the Java language for this.

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet 1");
  Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
  header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Header 1");
```

[Click here to see image of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5czRg.png)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you provide the number of column as a parameter and in your case this is column #0. If you would like to work with third column just change the number of column: `header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Header 1");`

More about usage of this method you can read in javadoc [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#createCell-int-).